# Several verbal complement for "warn"

Tags: verbs, negation, imperative-sentences

Consider:

> The government warned Tehran's citizens to stay at home, close windows, **don't walk in streets**, don't sport in parks and finally try to travel to another city if they can.

Must it be "not to walk"?

Comment: ....warned not to walk...

Comment: ....., not to walk in streets, not to sport in parks, and finaly try to.....

Comment: Also "don't sport in parks" sounds very non-fluent.  We don't usually use *sport* as a verb that way, we say *to play sports*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**warned** is followed by a (marked) infinitive complement, as indirect speech:

> We were warned *to stay* indoors.

or by the imperative, in which case it is quoted direct speech

> We were warned, "*Stay* indoors, *do not come* outside, ... *try* to travel...".

We tend  not to mix the two options when writing careful prose, but a speaker might in the heat of the moment; here's an example with a similar verb, **order**:

> We were ordered to climb walls, to crawl under barbed wire, to peel potatoes and dig latrines—Do this, Do that!—man, I really hated Army boot camp.

And a careless writer or one not bothering to follow punctuation conventions might not use quotation marks when mixing them.

To negate an infinitive:

> warned ... to stay indoors, *not to use* Twitter ...

If adhering to the "rule" not to mix direct and indirect speech, you would mark the infinitive throughout with **to**:

> warned ... not to walk in the streets ... and finally, **to** try to travel to another city...

as the unmarked infinitive and the direct imperative have the same form.

Answer (score 0):

> don't walk in *(the)* streets
>   *stay off the streets*

is an idiom meaning "don't go outside"

> don't walk

can be understood to have the meaning "you are not allowed to walk, but you may run" but your passage has more the meaning of "stay inside".

Comment: Thank you, but I mean from the grammar perspective.